# Getting List of Factors in a monomial. Is FactorList reliable?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

Say I'm given a monomial which is a product of factors,
$X_{i_1} \times \cdots \times X_{i_n}$.
I find that

```
FactorList[X Y Z Y ....]
(* {{1,1},{X,1},{Y,2},{Z,1}...} *)
```

is the input/output for whatever example I give. I like this because it lets me do some manipulations.

My question is, do we find

```
FactorList[X1^{a1} ... Xn^{an}]
(* {{1,1},{X1,a1},...,{Xn,an}} *)
```

in that order in all cases (say that $a1,...,an$ are nonnegative integers)? If not, what operation can I use?

---

NOTE: In my use cases, the subscripts $i_1,\cdots,i_n$ will be more complicated. E.g. for

```
term = Subscript[W,{1,2},{a,b,c}] Subscript[X,{y,y},{c,c,a}] Subscript[Y,{1},{1,1}]
```

FactorList still seems to work, although I'm worried that more complicated inputs could mess up what I want.

Comment: "in that order"? Possibly not. `Times` is `Orderless` and the factors will be reordered into standard order as necessary. It seems `FactorList` respects the order the factors appear in `Times`, but that is not documented AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but an extended comment:

- As a practical matter, I would make a list of all (types of) variables that could conceivably appear in the monomials and simply try if `FactorList` works as expected. If it does, then maybe that is good enough. It may not be good enough if one is writing a package or other code for a third party.
- If more control is necessary (and OPs question is about "reliability") then I would avoid calling a relatively sophisticated function such as `FactorList`, whose purpose is to factor polynomials, for the lesser task of listing the factors of a monomial. In that case, one could write a simple function such as

  ```
  monomialFactorList[a_]:=Replace[Switch[Head[a],Times,List@@a,_,{a}],
                                  Power[u_,v_:1]:>{u,v},{1}];
  ```

  to perform essentially the same task. The advantage is that it is transparent what this function does.
- I would usually avoid something like `Subscript[W,{1,2},{a,b,c}]` in a symbolic calculation. Instead I would use `W[{1,2},{a,b,c}]`, and if necessary, set the output format using

  ```
  Format[W[p_,q_]]:=Subsuperscript[W,p,q]
  ```